# WSO2 APIM not providing custom claims with user schema

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I using `WSO2 APIM (API Manager)` version `1.9.1` release working on JWT assertion concept. I found some useful links, shown below:

1. http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.in/2015/05/use-openid-with-oauth-20-in-wso2-api.html
2. http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/09/openid-connect-support-with-resource-owner-password-grant-type/#comment-21792

I created my own SP (service provide) and created some custom claims their under Claim Configuration and Inbound Authentication Configuration,`OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration`

As per link:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=openid" -H "Authorization: Basic M1J6RFNrRFI5ZmQ5czRqY296R2xfVjh0QU5JYTpXeElqSkFJd0dqRWVYOHdHZGFfcGM1Wl94RjRh, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

It gives us

```
{"scope":"openid","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,
"refresh_token":"65af3dbea3294b1524832d3869361e3e",
"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE0MzA0NTY4MzM5OTgsImV4cCI6MTQzMDQ2MDQzNDAxNCwic3ViIjoiYWRtaW5AY2FyYm9uLnN1cGVyIiwiYXpwIjoiM1J6RFNrRFI5ZmQ5czRqY296R2xfVjh0QU5JYSIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJNV013WXpreVl6UmxPVGhsTkRNM01XTTVNVFEyTTJWbE0yWXlNamcwWXc9PSIsImF1ZCI6WyIzUnpEU2tEUjlmZDlzNGpjb3pHbF9WOHRBTklhIl0sImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6OTQ0M1wvb2F1dGgyZW5kcG9pbnRzXC90b2tlbiIsImlhdCI6MTQzMDQ1NjgzNDAxNH0.Fc4DO8A22euo04vnBoE87RVBtDQ-73Z2hNZ8_WpeKslkumhEuUVcf6y03D5HZBlGDUi8zC1SUHewg4WEE8HvI6wA59wp8BErK6pY3Zb02pWbJsPh7VBHwky2g5PtvKSsGiy0rd2tuehY-_dAy7LBKNSUOhkmGdLXkSSThuIQxKOHDAJKHCY4I_36B9OH1scs34EG9MKG4vSNdfdcf4mSg0KUD98Jdw_NS-T4pRZK_sCeT-1BBodYEabEVREHxfcDr7BGYugMiiWThVUzd4WIHD83bVwxXP17POzuo6dS_l78pBWZtBBMPKXqhd9VMNZpc-sR07DS7KkHoV6Fp3l0oA",
"access_token":"1c0c92c4e98e4371c91463ee3f2284c"}
```

But when we called following we're only getting default user schema details, it's not showing our custom claims in output.

```
curl -k -v -H "Authorization: Bearer 1c0c92c4e98e4371c91463ee3f2284c" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid

{
 "phone_number":"54326643565",
 "email":"mkyong@yahoo.com",
 "family_name":"Yong",
 "country":"Japan"
}
```

Why it's not giving anyother custom claims configured with SP? Any help ?

```
{
   "iss":"wso2.org/products/am",
   "exp":1391029971429,
   "http://wso2.org/claims/subscriber":"admin",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationid":"1",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationname":"DefaultApplication",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/applicationtier":"Unlimited",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/apicontext":"/pizzashack/menu",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/version":"1.0.0",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/tier":"Bronze",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/keytype":"PRODUCTION",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/usertype":"APPLICATION",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/enduser":"admin",
   "http://wso2.org/claims/enduserTenantId":"-1234"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in api manger after subscribe to application, API Store would register an OAuth subscription automatically. Therefore unnecessary to configure service provider for OAuth subscription.

The  custom claim configuration not  enabled there in the api-manager.xml by default. Therefore, you must add the configuration parameters to the API authentication handler.

To configure custom dialect copy the following into the  <APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml file under the `<APIConsumerAuthentication>` tag.

```
<SecurityContextHeader>X-JWT-Assertion</SecurityContextHeader>
<ClaimsRetrieverImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever</ClaimsRetrieverImplClass>
<ConsumerDialectURI>http://wso2.org/claims</ConsumerDialectURI>
<SignatureAlgorithm>SHA256withRSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
<EnableTokenGeneration>true</EnableTokenGeneration>
<TokenGeneratorImpl>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.JWTGenerator</TokenGeneratorImpl>
```

After configuring custom dialect add new claim mapping.While adding the custom claim mappings select “Supported by Default” ( Supported by Default=true). Once complete go to Home   > Configure > Users and Roles >  User.   Select the user and update the newly added field appear in the user profile. You may see the user details in the JWT.

Refernce -https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Adding+New+Claim+Mapping